# Is there a way to use the SHORT system time picture in C++/MFC?

Tags: c++, time, mfc, system

I have an MFC dialog with a time control.  Currently, if I change the 'Long time' format on my PC (for example in Win7 -> Region and Language -> Long time), the dialog will follow suit and display in the selected format.  However, I do not need the seconds to be displayed.  Is there a way that I can pull the 'Short time' picture instead?

I know that I can remove the seconds by using .SetFormat on the control, but this hard codes whatever format I enter and does not allow the user to switch between standard and military times (which is required).

Comment: I did find a blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/12/18/505141.aspx) that basically says the answer is no for a Win32 program. You could do it under .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mr Lister.  I'm going to try a few more things short of parsing it to what I want, but in light of your provided link, I may just end up leaving it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [GetLocaleInfoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/dd318103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the format string for the short date (ie LOCALE_SSHORTDATE) for your user's locale setting and pass that to SetFormat method.